# How to use two integers to represent integral part of double

Tags: actionscript, timestamp, double, int

I'm getting a millisec timestamp in ActionScript as a Number object which can return a primitive double. I'd like to cast it for a backend that expects a primitive long long millisec, however the language does not provide long long. Am thinking a double can be converted to two ints and submitted together. Any encounter something like this and have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You might as well just convert your double to an int in ActionScript. You won't lose any accuracy because in ActionScript doubles and ints have the same bit depth. Then the conversion from int to long long should be automatic.

Comment: while they might have the same bit depth, he'll lose everything after the decimal point

Comment: a timestamp in a double with a value like 1315188404644 is too large to fit a single 32 bit int. it would need to span across two ints (or unsigned ints).